# Is it possible to print a particular section of log file?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have a log file and I want to print the Ethernet Address in below file using a C program. So how can I do that? My log file is given below:

```
*Thu Dec 25 11:40:41 2014; ******** LAN traffic monitor started ********** LAN traffic log, generated Thu Dec 25 11:41:41 2014


Ethernet address: 08:00:27:d7:54:fa
    Incoming total 389 packets, 184398 bytes; 388 IP packets
    Outgoing total 383 packets, 64444 bytes; 382 IP packets
    Average rates:     24.58 kbps incoming,      8.59 kbps outgoing
    Last 5-second rates:      0.86 kbps incoming,      0.45 kbps outgoing

Ethernet address: 52:54:00:12:35:02
    Incoming total 383 packets, 64444 bytes; 382 IP packets
    Outgoing total 389 packets, 184398 bytes; 388 IP packets
    Average rates:      8.59 kbps incoming,     24.58 kbps outgoing
    Last 5-second rates:      0.45 kbps incoming,      0.86 kbps outgoing

Running time: 60 seconds

*** LAN traffic log, generated Thu Dec 25 11:42:41 2014


iEthernet address: 08:00:27:d7:54:fa
    Incoming total 395 packets, 184935 bytes; 393 IP packets
    Outgoing total 389 packets, 64805 bytes; 387 IP packets
    Average rates:     12.33 kbps incoming,      4.32 kbps outgoing
    Last 5-second rates:      0.00 kbps incoming,      0.00 kbps outgoing

Ethernet address: 52:54:00:12:35:02
    Incoming total 389 packets, 64805 bytes; 387 IP packets
    Outgoing total 395 packets, 184935 bytes; 393 IP packets
    Average rates:      4.32 kbps incoming,     12.33 kbps outgoing
    Last 5-second rates:      0.00 kbps incoming,      0.00 kbps outgoing

Running time: 120 seconds
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Note that your question is ambiguous in that you've not defined precisely what output you want from the sample data (but it is good that you included the sample data).  It is also a good idea to show what you've tried.  It is not clear whether a shell script is sufficient, or whether you really need a C program.  I'd expect to use `sed` or `grep` for the task, and would use `awk` or Perl or Python for more complex processing before writing C code to do the job.  All of these are C programs; they are not custom C programs, though.

Comment: If You realy need to write C program, regex functions may be usefull (see `regcomp()`, `regexec()` etc manual pages on Your system).

Answer (score 1):

1) Open the log file with `fopen()`.

2) Read line by line with `fgets()`.

3) Search each line for the key phrase "Ethernet address" with `strstr()`.

4) Print such lines with `printf()`.

5) Close the file with `fclose()`.

Answer (score 1):

What constitutes a 'section' of the log file?

- If you mean the single lines containing 'Ethernet address', then it is easy with `grep` or `sed`:

  ```
  grep 'Ethernet address' logfile
  sed -n '/Ethernet address/p' logfile
  ```
- If you mean the block of lines starting 'Ethernet address', then it is easy with `sed` and doable with GNU `grep` if the size of the block is fixed:

  ```
  sed -n '/Ethernet address/,/^$/p' logfile
  grep -A 5 'Ethernet address' logfile
  ```

  Both commands include the blank line in the output.  If that's not wanted, then:

  ```
  sed -n '/Ethernet address/,/^$/{ /^$/d; p;}' logfile
  grep -A 4 'Ethernet address' logfile
  ```
- If you really want to write a C program for the job, it is certainly doable, and if you have a decent set of libraries to support you, not very hard.  It'd be less than 30 lines of code actually processing files (whichever way you wanted blocks processed), plus maybe 80 lines of supporting code for argument processing etc. (depending on how many options you support, and how flexible the program should be in general), plus the library functions.  It also depends a bit on how firmly you want 'Ethernet address' hardwired into the C program (hint: you probably don't want it hardwired into the program).

Note that the code shown will select the '`iEthernet address`' line shown in the data.  If that's not a typo and that block isn't wanted, use a caret (`^`) before `Ethernet` in each place where it occurs.